# curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: curl

I'm trying to use `curl`, yet running into following issue:

```
# curl -v --cacert ./ca.crt --key ./private/X.key --cert ./issued/X.crt https://X.X.X
* Rebuilt URL to: https://X.X.X/
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to X.X.X (X.X.X.X) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ./ca.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
# 
# curl --version
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2s zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.18.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL 
#
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also tried running same curl command from another environment (same results):

```
# curl --version
curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP 
# cat /etc/debian_version 
8.11
#
```

yet running from yet another environment works w/out any issues:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.64.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1c zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.5 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.0.5) libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.36.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2019-02-06
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL 
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
kali-rolling
$
```

all environments are using up to date (latest) version of curl/openssl package that is available for OS.

---

I believe it has something to do with older version of curl and/or openssl doesn't support latest tlsv1.3 as working environment has this:

```
$ curl --help | grep -- --tlsv1.3
     --tlsv1.3       Use TLSv1.3 or greater
$
```

Comment: In my case it was the old version of curl from php 5.2.17: cURL Information => libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8q zlib/1.2.3

Comment: @b3wii tls1.3 was only introduced in openssl1.1.1

Answer (score 20):

I've got the same error when silly me used `https` instead of `http` while testing with `localhost`

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://localhost:8000/api/search
                                                    ^
                                                    ¯\_(ツ)
```

Hope this helps someone if they came across this post.

Comment: most likely one would must use following flag as well `-k, --insecure    Allow insecure server connections`

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into same problem while testing socket.io in localhost:3002 port. My problem was https instead of http. I changed https to http and it works.

my wrong command was: `curl "https://localhost:3002/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"`

my correct command was: `curl "http://localhost:3002/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/newrelic-infra.repo https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/yum/el/7/x86_64/newrelic-infra.repo
```

> ERROR curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

I HAD THE SAME ERROR BUT I SOLVED IT

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/yum/el/7/x86_64/newrelic-infra.repo
```