# error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version while using getURL()

Tags: r, xml, geturl

When I try using `getURL()` in the following way, I get an error:

```
library(RCurl)

getURL("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?retmode=xml&db=pubmed&sort=pub+date&api_key=94fb5e3a815482d7c32927d002fb8f45e308&id=24190502")
```

The error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Any ideas on how I could resolve this?

Comment: You are probably using an old version of SSL not supporting up-to-date TLS versions, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56981213/8245406) and [here](https://support.itrsgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022122613-What-are-the-common-error-codes-when-monitoring-HTTPS-websites-with-Web-Mon-plugin-).